# Why does Facebook scraper ignore my meta-tag?

Tags: html, facebook, metadata, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

When I scrape a url in facebook the meta tags are ignored. But in other social media platforms it works.. Example link: https://www.viro-group.com/nl/nieuws/viro-opent-nieuwe-vestiging-in-zwolle/

My code in the head:

```
<meta name="og:title" content="{{ entry.title }} - {{ siteName }}">
<meta name="og:description" content="{{entry.metaBeschrijving}}">
<meta name="og:url" content="{{ entry.url }}" />
<meta name="og:type" content="article" />
<meta name="og:site_name" content="VIRO">
<meta content="{{ img.url }}" property="og:image:secure_url" >
<meta name="og:image:alt" content="{{ entry.title }}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

The Debugger said that you did not share the URL yet. I fetched it with the Debugger and now it works perfectly fine: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.viro-group.com%2Fnl%2Fnieuws%2Fviro-opent-nieuwe-vestiging-in-zwolle

Data shows up when i try to post the URL on Facebook too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But it it still not fixt. In the errorr/warning I get the following:



**Inferred Property**
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.


**Missing Properties**
The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

Comment: i would not worry too much about those warnings, if you scroll down you will see that the og tags are filled correctly. remember, those are only warnings, they may appear wrong, and the most important thing is: it works on facebook :)

Answer (score 0):

You might use property instead of name :

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ entry.title }} - {{ siteName }}">
<meta property="og:description" content="{{entry.metaBeschrijving}}">
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ entry.url }}" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="VIRO">
<meta content="{{ img.url }}" property="og:image:secure_url" >
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="{{ entry.title }}" >
```